# Как открывать страницу только после авторизации?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Сделал регистрацию, сделал авторизацию, все работает и я собой горжусь. Но проблема вот в чем, если пользователь наберет в браузере строку, допустим, `www.какой_то_сайт.ru/chat/index.php`, то он тупа обойдет авторизацию, регистрацию, ему выведется страница, но без сессии. Хотелось бы, чтобы даже если он набирает такую строку, то как-то возвращало к авторизации. Как это реализовать? С помощью куков или сессии? Помогите, а?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один вариант:

```
   $H=getenv("HTTP_REFERER"); // получаем URL, с которого пришёл посетитель
```

Comment: а можно по подробнее не много?) начинающий, что взять. или где можно про это почитать?

Comment: 1. [Get a Referral URL from the Session using PHP](http://www.vonfelten.com/blog/2007/06/05/referral-url-from-session-using-php/)
2. [$HTTP_SERVER_VARS [deprecated]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
3. [Узнаем REFERER посетителя](http://ruinet.info/index.php?kod=275)

P.S: Имейте ввиду, что это не готовый ответ, а один из вариантов, которые могут понадобится для решения задачи. Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!$login) echo '<h3>Необходима авторизация!</h3><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://my-site.ru/auth.php">';
```

Comment: спасибо, оказалось все проще чем можно представить) честно думал надо проверять как-то сессию или куки))) спасибо

Comment: иногда ломаешь голову, а оказывается все на много проще)

Comment: Да не за что ))